# Eliminating Out of Bounds error in Java sorting comparison

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I'm currently implementing InsertionSort and MergeSort to do a comparison on their operations, I have implemented MergeSort before but am trying the version in my current algorithms textbook. I am getting an array out of bounds error on the line marked by comments (line 58) and once it gets past it I would assume also probably on line 60. This is the algorithm in the book to the T but I can't find where my error comes from. Code includes simplistic main method to test, full code is included so it is copyable and runnable.

```
package algsortcomp;


public class AlgSortComp {


public static void InsertionSort(int[] data){
    //Sorts given array by Insertion Sort
    //Input: an array data of ints
    //Output: array data sorted in nondecreasing 
    int v, j;
    for (int i = 1; i<data.length; i++){
        v = data[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && data[j] > v){
            data[j+1] = data[j--];
        }
        data[j+1]=v;
    }
}

public static void MergeSort(int[] data){
    //Sorts array data by recursive mergesort
    //Input: an array data of ints
    //Output: array data sorted in nondecreasing order
    int dlen = data.length;
    int mid = dlen/2;

    int[] b = new int[mid];
    int[] c = new int[dlen-mid];

    if (dlen > 1){
       System.arraycopy(data, 0, b, 0, mid-1);
       System.arraycopy(data, mid, c, 0, dlen-mid);
       MergeSort(b);
       MergeSort(c);
       Merge(b, c, data);
   }         
}

public static void Merge(int[] b, int[] c, int[] data){
    //Merges two sorted arrays into one sorted array
    //Input: Arrays b and c both sorted
    //Output: Sorted array data of elements b and c.
    int p = b.length, q = c.length, dlen = data.length;
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    while (i<p && j<q){
        if (b[i] <= c[j])
            data[k] = b[i++];
        else
            data[k]=c[j++];
        k++;
    }
    if (i == p)
        System.arraycopy(c, j, data, k, dlen-1); //<---currently getting Array out of bounds here, tried replacing with
    else                                         //dlen-k and error is gone but array returned is all [0,0,...,0]
        System.arraycopy(b, i, data, k, dlen-1);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] test = {3, 5, 23, 56, 1, 12, 32};
    String arraystr = java.util.Arrays.toString(test);
    System.out.println(arraystr);

    //InsertionSort(test);
    MergeSort(test);
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(test));
}

}
```

nobody from class is awake yet so I ask you humble folk for an extra eye to spot my error. Thanks in advance.

edit: also I forget how to call java.util.Arrays.toString() by just Arrays.toString(). I tried importing java.util.Arrays but that didn't work and it has admittedly been quite a while since I've touched java/arrays.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Why not debug the code using IDE like eclipse?

Comment: All I have is netbeans and have never used the debugger feature if it has one. Does netbeans have the capability also or would I need eclipse?

Comment: Yes Netbeans too have debug feature. Just do little R&D using Google you will get the way.!

Comment: See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joWldbcp1So

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.arraycopy` takes the number of elements to copy as the last parameter. Here, you want to copy the number of remaining items from c, which should be q-j. Similarly, p-i for the next case.

Are you `import java.util.Arrays` **after** the `package` line?

Also, change this `System.arraycopy(data, 0, b, 0, mid-1);` to

`System.arraycopy(data, 0, b, 0, mid);`

Comment: When I do this I get the same result as trying dlen-k, the array ends up as [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32]

Comment: make this `System.arraycopy(data, 0, b, 0, mid-1);` to ` System.arraycopy(data, 0, b, 0, mid);`

Comment: Also changed to p-i and still get [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32] as final array.

Comment: [1, 3, 5, 12, 23, 32, 56]!! thank you, that mid-1 was what was doing it. Thank you.

Comment: Aye I did, right before you said that :P +1 too for whatever that's worth.